# Question regarding "dry spots" with latex paint

Tags: paint

I've ran into a bit of a problem when painting a wall in our home today. We're in the process of redoing our stairwell, and one of the walls had a fairly noticeable paint run in it. The wall itself is a relatively small surface area, and so I decided to sand the wall down to remove the run. After wiping the wall down and letting it dry, I repainted it. The wall is very patchy / blotchy looking, and you can see "dry" spots all over it when light hits the surface. How do I go about fixing this?

Should I have primered before repainting? The paint we're using is Valspar with Satin finish. If primering wont fix the appearance, would putting a thin skim coating on the wall help? I was thinking it may help even out the surface a bit, and then i can just prime and paint that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both original and new paint are latex, try another coat on the problem areas. That should clear up the dry spots.

In the future, you'll probably get better results with primer+finish. And I wouldn't skim unless the surface was really lumpy.